Problem with the texture of the eyes. Reflects HDR rather than eye texture
Does anyone know what this is? The texture of the eyes focuses this way. Reflecting HDR, rather than eye texture. This happens on a few different rigs. Including Rain, from Blender itself. Does anyone know what could be happening??


Looks like it's too glossy, add some roughness

It looks like you are in Material Preview in your Viewport Shading. Is this really a render ? What is you material ? Without more informations, you won't get far.

This is expected behavior for EEVEE and material preview. EEVEE does not support real refraction, so it fakes it using the world background. If you mean this to be an EEVEE render, you’d better use a mixture of Transparent and Glossy shaders instead of Glass, or turn on screen space reflection and refraction in both the render settings and the materials in question (the materials only have the refraction setting). It’s not perfect, but it’ll work.

He can go into the eevee settings and turn on screen space reflections and refractions, then go into the individual materials and turn on screen space refractions there as well. These are off by default to keep eevee performant
